# Why url parameter is indexed at 'named' instead of 'pass' in cakephp?

Tags: url, cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-2.x

My url is: http://localhost/intranet/customers/search/1/1A%3A79%3A32%3A97%3AF2/1
I am printing the params object as follows:

```
print_r($this->params);
```

This print the following array:

```
[params] => Array
        (
            [plugin] => 
            [controller] => customers
            [action] => search
            [named] => Array
                (
                    [1A] => 79:32:97:F2
                )

            [pass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )
```

but it should print:

```
[params] => Array
        (
            [plugin] => 
            [controller] => customers
            [action] => search
            [named] => Array
                (

                )

            [pass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 1A:79:32:97:F2
                    [2] => 1
                )
        )
```

But when I change the url like: http://localhost/intranet/customers/search/1/abc/1

```
[params] => Array
        (
            [plugin] => 
            [controller] => customers
            [action] => search
            [named] => Array
                (

                )

            [pass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => abc
                    [2] => 1
                )
        )
```

Which problem with 1A:79:32:97:F2 as parameter in url?

Comment: you probably need to encode those `:`

Comment: You should not be using the depracted named params since CakePHP 2.0 (The year 2011). See [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/). Use query strings instead for non alphanumeric data. For simple (and ordered) alphanumeric data you can use passed - but make sure those are properly slugged then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable the greediness of named parameter parsing, by default all parameters that look like named parameters are being parsed as such (that is values that contain the `:` separator).

In your routes configuration, use the second argument of `Router::connectNamed()` to pass further options, something along the lines of this, which would enable only the default CakePHP pagination paramters:

```
Router::connectNamed(
    false, // no custom named parameters
    array(
        'default' => true, // default pagination parameters
        'greedy' => false  // no greediness
    )
);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Development > Routing > Controlling Named Parameters](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#controlling-named-parameters)**